# R: numerical values read as character

Tags: r

I am reading a csv file which has columns as below

```
    V6          V7
1   232.2       448.0
2     8.0       11.7
3   744.5       1,220.6
4    72.6       277.3
5   579.8       1,007.4
6    79.4       88.9
7    55.7       127.4
8   480.7       1,138.3
9   848.3       3,246.8
10 -477.7       5,084.2
11  958.2       3,954.2
```

The output of `str(df)`

```
$ V6 : num  232.2 8 744.5 72.6 579.8 ...
$ V7 : chr  "448.0" "11.7" "1,220.6" "277.3" ...
```

The way I read the file is

```
df = read.csv("data.csv", skip = 1, header = FALSE, as.is = TRUE)
```

I tried to change the type of `V7` as

```
df$V7 = as.numeric(df$V7)
```

However, I get lot's of `NAs` due to coercion. Probably it is due to the ",". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a post-processing:

```
df$V7 = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df$V7))
```